# Interp1 not defined in Octave GUI for Windows

Tags: user-interface, octave

Is anyone else getting the error: `interp1 undefined near line...` when using the Octave GUI (Octave version 4.0.0) on Windows 10? I was just at another computer using Debian and it worked fine.

**Update:** just checked it again by SSH'ing into that Debian server and it recognized `interp1`. Not sure why the difference on Windows version of Octave GUI.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Octave?

Comment: `interp1` is a `.m` file... did you check to make sure it's in the proper directory?